# Linking a Ticket in Trac to a Changeset

Tags: svn, commit, trac, changeset

By using Intertrac we are able to link the change set to a ticket using the syntax:

*prefix:#ticketnumber*

This is useful when viewing change sets and seeing which tickets it links to. I also noticed you can do a search on the above link and it will return all the changesets pertaining to that ticket, my question is

How can we insert a link to a change set in a ticket during the commit process, or can this on be done through a post-commit-hook?

It would be nice to be able to look at a single ticket and view the change sets that pertain to that ticket?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.  The post commit hook script is the way to go.

http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/contrib/trac-post-commit-hook

I'm currently using it and it works great to give you the history of changesets for a given ticket.

Comment: OK, I looked into that earlier today and it was giving me endless troubles, end up with a MERGE 100 OK error, and then I have to update the local file manually.  I will spend some more time looking into that and hopefully sort out that problem, then look into adding in some script to update the comment of the ticket to link to the changeset.
thanks